# Kendo-ui-angular2 grid Horizontal scrolling issue in IE 11

Tags: angular, kendo-grid, kendo-ui-angular2

I faced with lack of performance in IE 11 when trying to scroll Kendo UI Angular2 grid horizontally. From time to time number of columns may changed. At least I have 30 columns each time. IE either freeze UI for more than 10 seconds, or even crashed.

My grid version is 0.5.0. Here is my grid settings:

```
<kendo-grid
    [data]="view"
    [scrollable]="'virtual'"
    [height]="gridHeight"
    [pageSize]="pageSize"
    [rowHeight]="rowHeight"
    [skip]="skip"
    [sortable]="{ mode: 'multiple' }"
    [sort]="sort"
    (sortChange)="sortChange($event)"
    (pageChange)="pageChange($event)">
    <template ngFor [ngForOf]="columns" let-column>
        <kendo-grid-column
            field="{{column}}"
            [headerStyle]="{'border': 'none', 'font-size': 'medium'}"
            [width]="computeWidth(column)"
            [style]="{'border': 'none', 'font-size': 'small'}">
            <template kendoCellTemplate let-dataItem>
                <div>
                    {{dataItem[column] | truncate : 75 }}
                </div>
            </template>
        </kendo-grid-column>
    </template>
</kendo-grid>
```

EDIT: update grid up to 0.6.2, same thing with IE even Chrome thinking longer than expected.
Example is [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/wFHhdRzUf2n6AYlY63Nr)

Comment: Can you provide a runnable sample that shows the `computeWidth` function and at least a row of mocked data?

Comment: Please provide a bit of instructions how to perform this?

Comment: You can use the `Open in Plunker` button from one of the examples on the [documentation site](www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/grid/), to bootstrap the example. Then you can add your code in the `app/app.component.ts` file, until the plunker shows the problem.

Comment: Hello, Alex!
Here http://plnkr.co/edit/wFHhdRzUf2n6AYlY63Nr is my example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using virtual scrolling, don't bind the grid to the complete data (thousands of rows), but only to the currently paged data. This is what makes the virtual scrolling fast -- only the currently visible data is rendered. This is shown in the [virtual scrolling example in the documentation](http://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/grid/#scroll-modes).

```
private loadProducts(): void {
    this.gridData = {
        data: this.data.slice(this.skip, this.skip + this.pageSize),
        total: this.data.length
    };
}
```

See the [updated plunker snippet](http://plnkr.co/edit/vEUUyUSHegQp63bHUnf1?p=preview).

Comment: Thank you! And what about filtering and sorting in 0.6.2 version?

Comment: You can use the [DataQuery package](http://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/dataquery/) to process the data. See the [sorting example](http://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/grid/#sorting). The filtering UI is not yet available -- it will be introduced in a future version.